# How to conditionally join in a T-SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a fairly simple stored procedure to begin with:

```
    @intDeptID INT
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        product_id, product_code
    FROM
        Products p
    JOIN
        ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
    JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription = pc.ProductCategoryDescription
    WHERE 
        d.Dept_ID = @intDeptID
    ORDER BY
        product_code
```

The problem is that there is one instance where the `DepartmentDescription` is not equal to the `CategoryDescription`, which is `@intDeptID = 16`

I want to make a conditional such that when `@intDeptID = 16`, I use the following joins:

```
JOIN 
    ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
JOIN
    Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription = 'SpecificCategory'
```

I'm sure I am going about this the wrong way - so feel free to enlighten me with the proper way to do this. I keep thinking `IF-THEN` and `CASE` statements, but that doesn't seem to work (at least the way I have constructed them in my many tests).

Comment: the proper way is to use a LEFT JOIN and join all the tables as you normally would

Comment: Aside: `if`/`then`/`else` is a control-of-flow statement, `case` is an expression (like `iif` or `choose`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JOIN 
    ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
JOIN
    Department d ON (
        d.DepartmentDescription = 'SpecificCategory'
        AND d.Dept_ID=16
    ) OR (
        d.DepartmentDescription = pc.ProductCategoryDescription
        AND d.Dept_ID<>16
    )
```

OR

```
JOIN 
    ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
JOIN
    Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription =
        CASE
            WHEN d.Dept_ID=16 THEN 'SpecificCategory'
            ELSE pc.ProductCategoryDescription
        END
```

Comment: `AND AND d.Dept_ID<>16`?

Comment: @HABO no idea what you are talking about :P

Answer (score 1):

You could just include the variable in the `JOIN` such that it uses one or the other depending upon the circumstances:

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, product_code
From Products p
    Join ProductCategory pc on pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
    Join Department d on @intDeptID != 16 AND d.DepartmentDescription=pc.ProductCategoryDescription
    Join Department d2 on @intDeptID = 16 AND d2.DepartmentDescription='SpecificCategory'
```

In this case you would have to use `COALESCE` to allow the values from `d` and `d2` to be amalgamated.  Something like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(d.department_column, d2.department_column) AS department_column
```

This would output whichever was non-null and return it in your result set.

Comment: Trying to get this working, but maybe I'm not understanding where to put the COALESCE :(

Answer (score 1):

You can join both options, and use the one that you want through a case construct.

```
  @intDeptID INT
AS
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        product_id, product_code
    FROM
        Products p
    LEFT JOIN
        ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription = pc.ProductCategoryDescription
    LEFT JOIN 
        Department d16 ON d16.DepartmentDescription = 'SpecificCategory'
    WHERE 
        CASE WHEN @intDeptID <> 16 then d.Dept_ID  else d16.Dept_ID  end = @intDeptID
    ORDER BY
        product_code
```

Notice that I have used LEFT JOINS, so if a correspondence isn't found for both joins it still returns a row.

Another solution is to simply use a general IF on your stored procedure to execute two different queries depending on @intDeptID value.

```
  @intDeptID INT
AS
  IF @intDeptID <> 16 begin 
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        p.product_id, p.product_code,
    FROM
        Products p
    LEFT JOIN
        ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
    LEFT JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription = pc.ProductCategoryDescription
    WHERE 
        d.Dept_ID = @intDeptID
    ORDER BY
        product_code
  END
  ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        product_id, product_code,
    FROM
        Products p
    LEFT JOIN
        ProductCategory pc ON pc.ProductCategoryID = p.ProductCategoryID
    JOIN 
        Department d ON d.DepartmentDescription = 'SpecificCategory'
    WHERE 
        d.Dept_ID = @intDeptID
    ORDER BY
        product_code
  END
```